# Previous and next button of calendra not displayed in ui.How to overcome this issue?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I am adding calendar with jQuery

Here is my jQuery code of calendar

```
$(function() {
   $( "#dob" ).datepicker();
}
);
```

but the next and previous button cannot be seen in user interface.

please suggest me wher do i have mistaken.

you can check here - http://screencast.com/t/idXD2qYlgk

please help

Comment: An image of the datepicker is just priceless, tells us everything we need!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the css , js like this and check once..

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am facing same issue, can we solve it by some other way? I tried to link the above files after downloading those from same url,but still having this issue. Please guide me.

Comment: the images aren't  loaded , check the console , try using the url as above , that will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

**Try inspecting with firebug** the prev and next buttons might me there but as the sprite image is not loaded properly you the buttons are not visible. This type of problems occurs commonly but are simple to be solved !